# How to format a short inline code in a paragraph of text?

Tags: formatting

If I have a paragraph of text and have some very short code inline such as a function/symbol names in the sentences, how to format them more like code?  Sort of like an analogue of `computerCode` in Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

As you are typing, you can toggle between `Code` and `Text` styles using `Alt+8` and `Alt+7` (version 9.0.1.0 windows 8 x64)

If the paragraph is already typed, you can highlight the part you want to change and use `Alt+8` to change its style to `Code`.
Or, you can use `Format` menu and select `Code` in the `Style` sub-menu.

Alternatively, you can use `Style[#,"Code"]` to change the style of selected elements. For example:

```
text = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}], 400]; 

reStyle = TextCell[Row[List @@ StringReplace[#,  p : Alternatives @@ #2 :> Style[p, "Code"]]], 16, 
              "Panel"] &;

reStyle[text, {"Integer", "condimentum", "porttitor", "vitae", "rutrum", "justo"}]
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for v11. It generates an all-gray area with the code blocks in bold

Comment: Thank you @glS. Looks like `"Panel` style definition has been modifed  since version 9 to add a gray background. Does adding  the option `Background->None` in `TextCell` work in version 11?

Comment: nope. It makes the background white, but the code blocks also have a white background.